# GridView not showing all the data

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

Result.java:

```
Fragment f = new GridViewFragement();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid, f).commit();
```

Activity_result.xml :

```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/grid"
       android:orientation="vertical"

    >

</LinearLayout>
```

Row_grid.xml: defines a grid item

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="5dp" >

  <ImageView

    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/home" >
 </ImageView>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" >
 </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

grid.xml:

```
         <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
       />
```

On create in grid view fragment:

```java
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // on create for activity


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, container, false);
        Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource
        (this.getResources(), R.drawable.home);
        Bitmap userIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource
        (this.getResources(),   R.drawable.personal);
        //
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"Personal"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Building"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"xyz"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"House"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"Friend"));



        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        customGridAdapter =newCustomGridViewAdapter
        (view.getContext(),R.layout.row_grid,gridArray);

        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

        return view;
     }
```

Having issues trying to show all data of my gridview. it cuts halfway only the first three items are showing in a row. sorry, I'm unable to post pictures because I'm only rep 1.
I have tried putting scrollviews and making the scroll bar appear but it just won't scroll or show all of its data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Grid view with 3 rows and 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796133/android-grid-view-with-3-rows-and-3-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see all of the rows you need to set layout_height=fill_parent 
not layout_width=fill_parent and layout_height=wrap_content. It won't be 
able to show all the rows though unless you make them all really small 
anyway depending on the number of cells you have. If you have a lot of cells 
then it is pointless to even try to get them to show up on one screen.

My suggestion is to go for list view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are concerned about the number of rows and columns displayed. If you are then you can use `numColumns` attribute to set the number of columns and the number of rows rely on the amount of data and number of columns. [see this for a better insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796133/android-grid-view-with-3-rows-and-3-columns/24796204)