# Android Grid view with 3 rows and 3 columns

Tags: android, android-gridview

I unable to set no. of rows for **grid view**. Only able to set no. of columns.

I need to create a grid view which has 3 rows and 3 columns.

Can any one help me please.

This is my `XML` layout code:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/gridView" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:numColumns="3" 
   android:gravity="center" 
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth" > 
</GridView>
```

Thanks in advance,
Deepak

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: If you have fixed number of rows and columns then why don't you go with `TableLayout`!

Comment: for columns you can use `android:numColumns` but for rows you must do that in your code

Comment: <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

Comment: it can't be because number of item may increase you can only set one parameter at a time . i think .

Comment: if you need to show only 3 rows,Specify that in gridview adapter getCount(). and print values inside getView() manually.

Answer (score 5):

Add this attribute to your android XML

```
android:numColumns="3"
```

This will allow you to have only 3 columns and give the

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Then add 3 rows may be it will help.

Try it.

Comment: zeus, thanks for you quick response. But how to add 3 rows. thats what my question :(

Comment: @Deepak if you want fixed rows you need get height of gridView then set height of each row to `viewhigh/ 3`,

Comment: to setup the three rows you have to setup total 9 elements in the List  or String array and use the ArrayAdapter to create the adapter to the gridView and then with the GridView object call the method setAdapter() and the setAdapter() needs the ArrayAdapter Object as the parameter.

Comment: @mzeus.bolt I have  a issue in Gridview can you please help me to solve .

Comment: What issue are you facing @Nikson

Comment: Please look it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963179/gridview-not-fit-for-all-screens-in-android @mzeus.bolt