# Gridview not fit for all screens in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am working in an Android app. In this I have an issue that my `GridView` and images are not get fit with all screen sizes .

**Here I have the gridview inside the fragment**

The `fragment_reminders.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_Gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/mGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And `gridview.xml` is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mImageView"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: As you've set `numColumns`, column width is redundant. Try removing that from `gridView`.

Comment: @tahsinRupam if I removed that it will display a single column

Comment: Do you want to keep the ImageView center aligned with text?

Comment: @ProkashSarkar ,yes exactly and also I want the gridview to get fit for all screen sizes

Comment: Set Top layout `RelativeLayout`  with `match_parent ,match_parent`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a GridLayout fit screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-make-a-gridlayout-fit-screen-size)

Comment: Hello Nikson, Rather than giving columnWidth as 100dp to GridView make it as match_parent then this will work fine for you.

Comment: @mzeus.bolt I can mark it as match_parent

Comment: @Nikson I will suggest you use `RecyclerView ` with `GridLayoutManager`

Comment: @NJ do you have any working examples

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the  Please check this

Comment: @Nikson Yes then it will work it as expected

Comment: @mzeus.bolt sorry typing error ,I can't mark it as match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridLayout` to acquire the desired result.Firstly **add** `gridLayout` **dependancy**:

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.1'
```

Then, add the following xml code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="3">

    <FrameLayout
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_alarm"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Alarms"/>
        </LinearLayout>

     </FrameLayout>

  </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

In the above code, I've just added 1 element. Just copy & paste this `FrameLayout` and change texts & images accordingly. After adding 12 elements, the output should look as below:

[image]

Comment: images and text are get aligned center but gridview is not get fit in the screen size

Comment: What is the problem you are facing exactly? Can you please elaborate or share a ss if possible?

Comment: I have 15 images I wanna arrange them in a 3 column and 5 rows combination, Images and text are showing well but it is not fit the screen as you can see in the above attached image .I want to make the gridview fit for all screen sizes

Comment: So you want to cover up the whole screen with `gridView` items?

Comment: is it possible to make it to get fit for all screens

Comment: Yes it is possible. You have to use `GridLayout` to fit for all screens. I'll add the sample code shortly.

Comment: looking for your suggestion ,Please get me soon

Comment: @Nikson please check the updated answer. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: so there is no need of ImageAdapter class ...?

Comment: If you use GridLayout, no. It's just a layout such as linearLayout. You can add views dynanically but it will not be necessary for fixed item. Btw, if the answer helps you can always upvote to encourage me ;)

Comment: I couldn't solved my issue...If you don't mind Can you take remote of my system and fix this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169532/discussion-between-tahsinrupam-and-nikson).

Comment: Please check the dropbox link

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwoing GridLayout,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:rowCount="5">

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

And change your GridLayout item to the following,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="1.5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mImageView"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

To use the `support.v7.widget.GridLayout` add the dependency,

`implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'`

*Haven't tested yet, but it should work.*

Comment: Have you added the gradle dependency?

Comment: What error are you getting? Don't forget to add : (xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto") in your parent LinearLayout with the id: linearlayout_Gridview

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: Check your java code, you need to import LayoutParams from LinearLayout instead of AbsListView.

Comment: After applying your suggestion this line throws error in fragment class(Reminders.java)

Comment: mGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(mRootView.getContext()));